RNGooglesignin.signin got 2 arguments, expected 3 error
I encountered a major error while implementing Google Login. I've been trying to resolve this issue for about four days, but I haven't been able to fix it, so I would like to ask for help.
import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithCredential, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

export const configureGoogleSignIn = () => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
        
        webClientId: '--webClientId--',
        
    });
};

export const signInWithGoogle = async (auth, navigation) => {
    try {
        
        await GoogleSignin.signOut();
        const playServices = await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({
            showPlayServicesUpdateDialog: true,
        });
        console.log('3. Play Services check:', playServices);
        const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
        const { idToken } = userInfo;
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
        const userCredential = await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
        const token = await userCredential.user.getIdToken();
    
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('@accessToken', token);
        navigation.navigate('Main');
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            console.log('SIGN_IN_CANCELLED');
        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
            console.log('SIGN_IN_PROGRESS');
        } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
            console.log('PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE');
        } else {
            console.error("Google Sign-In Error:", error);
            Alert.alert("Sign-In Error :", error.message);
        }
        throw error;
    }
};


const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn({});
The problem occurs in this code.
**Environment
**
Android Studio
Android API level 35
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^13.1.0"
"react-native": "^0.74.5"
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
I also cleared the
npm cache clean,
the yarn cache clean,
and tried ./gradlew.
Additionally, I also tried @react-native-google-signin/google-signin ver. 9.0.0 and 12.1.0.

Have you tried removing node_modules?
